# Setup gStreamer on Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android-studio, gstreamer

I'm trying to port one iOS App to Android, and this App uses gStreamer for video streaming in real-time. I'm a newbie in Android development, so can someone point me in the right direction, how to set-up this C/C++ library in Android Studio?

My machine:

Android Studio 1.3
Gradle 2.2.1